# Why does this result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at run-time?

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a= new int[3];
        System.out.print(a[a.length]);
    }
}
```

Why does this result in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptionwill at run-time?

Comment: because the index **start from 0 to 2** not **from 1 to 3** :)

Comment: Change to `System.out.print(a[a.length - 1])`

Comment: it shouldn't compile due to `newint[3];`

Comment: And `publicclassTest`

Answer (score 3):

`a.length` return the number of elements in the array, here it's 3.

Array index starts at 0. With 3 elements, it goes 0,1,2.

There is no index 3, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Index starts from `0` (not form `1`). So, in your case `a` has the index `0`, `1` and `2`.

But you are trying to access index `3` (`length` or `size`).

Use `System.out.print(a[a.length]-1);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use that:

```
public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int[] a= new int[3];
        System.out.print(a[a.length-1]);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`a.length` will return the **length** and that is **3** (3 existing fields).
But the index couting for `a[3]` starts with 0 and goes up to 2. 
Reducing the length with -1 returns the last really existing index (2).

So  `a[a.length]` (= `a[3]`) causes the Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception.

Comment: code without explanation is usually not helpful to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

It starts from 0 so you must Change to `[a.length - 1]`

```
 public class Test{
       public static void main(String []args){
          int[] a= new int[3];
          System.out.print(a[a.length-1]);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the hierarchy of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.lang.Throwable
        java.lang.Exception
            java.lang.RuntimeException
                java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

It is sometimes harder to solve it. During those moments, you can use IDLE debugger. It will show you the value of each variable at each iteration in the graphical interface.

You can use `Eclipse` debugger, `Netbeans`, `Visual Studio` code, `Atom` extensions works as well.